# Transforming a for loop with asynchronous operations inside

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I've an array of objects and when the user click a button I need to do the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayItems.length; i++) {
   var item = arrayItems[i];

    $.post(...)
       .fail(function(error) {

          // Abort the for loop

       })
       .done(function(data) {
          // Do some calculations with the item
             ...

          // Show a dialog box to write some extra data
          dialog.open(); // dialog is a Telerik Window widget
      });
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that the dialog box open in asynchronous way (I'm using Telerik Window widget for the dialog) so I need to transform the for loop to make the process synchronous.

Another question: How to abort the for loop if the post fail?

Can anyone please tell me how to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't want synchronous ajax, you probably just want to wait for all the calls to finish ?

Comment: I want to be able to stop the for loop execution until I close the dialog (it's a modal dialog) but the dialog open in asynchronous way so it doesn't stop :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your loop into a recursive function that calls `$.post` for the next item once it receives a response for the current item. If at anytime a fail happens, you can abort by simply stopping the recursion.

```
function fn(items, idx) {
  if (idx < items.length) {
    $.post(...)
      .fail(function(error) {
        // Abort the process by not calling `fn` recursively
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        dialog.open();
        // call `fn` recursively for the next item
        fn(items, idx + 1);
      });
  }
}
```

If you want to continue to the next item after the dialog is closed, I'm sure there's an `onclose` (or similar) hook for the dialog that you can use and just call `fn` inside of it instead.

```
function fn(items, idx) {
  if (idx < items.length) {
    $.post(...)
      .fail(function(error) {
        // Abort the process by not calling `fn` recursively
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        dialog.open({ 
          onClose: function() {
            // call `fn` recursively for the next item
            fn(items, idx + 1);
          }
        });
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: dialog.open() open the dialog asynchronous so I can't call fn(...) below it

Comment: is there an on close method you can attach to the dialog and call it in there?